# Mixed content after http -> https because of images. How change them in DB without plugin?

Tags: wordpress, https, mixed-content

recently I moved my wordpress site from http to https. I see mixed content errors because of images which are still requested via htttp.

How to fix it with sql scripts and without using any plugin?

I've already updated `post_content` and `guid` columns in `wp_posts` table.

`UPDATE wp_posts SET 'post_content' = REPLACE ('post_content', 'src="http://example.com', 'src="https://example.com');`

Comment: Did you check the rest of the images that are not part of your posts' content already? (eg. logo, ads, icons, etc).

Comment: Configure your server to add the Upgrade-Insecure-Requests response header to all responses.

Comment: @cabrerahector damn I didn't see that one of the images is logo of my Wordpress template. Guess I have to edit template files?

Comment: @sideshowbarker thanks, I will read about it